# How can I convert a binary string to a byte?

Tags: java, binary, byte, bit, huffman-code

I'm working on Huffman compression.

```
String binaryString = "01011110";
outFile.write(byte);
```

I have a String which I want to convert to a byte so that I can write that byte to the file. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: What is the actual starting info you have? Because the first line is obviously not correct, do you have a string `"01011110"` or do you have a string `"^"`?

Comment: It's supposed to be `String binaryString = "01011110";` .Sorry about that.

Comment: `Byte.parseByte("01011110", 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn that `String` into a numerical value using the overloaded `parseByte` that lets you specify the radix:

```
String binaryString = "01011110";
byte b = Byte.parseByte(binaryString, 2); //this parses the string as a binary number
outFile.write(b);
```

The second argument to `parseByte()` lets you specify the Number system in which the String should be parsed. By default, a radix of 10 is used because us humans usually use the decimal system. The 2 says that the number should be treated as a binary value (which is base 2).

Comment: Thank you! What does `2` mean on the second line?

Comment: It lets you specify the numerical system in which the String should be parsed. By default, a radix of 10 is used because us humans usually use the decimal system. The 2 says that the number should be treated as a binary value (which is base 2).

Comment: Ahh, okay! When my program comes to the next binaryString, I get this exception `NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"10000011" Radix:2`. What is wrong?

Comment: Byte can only represent numbers from -128 to 127, and 10000011 is 131.

Comment: You can use `byte i = (byte)(Integer.parseInt("10000011", 2) & 0xff)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Byte.parseByte()` with a radix of 2:

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte(str, 2);
```

example:

```
System.out.println(Byte.parseByte("01100110", 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Could write (a String[256] with each manually written 1 and 0 set of 8 bits) it out , its only 256 of them. gives you the ability to check with String.indexOf(binnum[arrayIndex])
and make a corresponding array of new byte[256] and set each in matching order with new Integer(increment).byteValue(), it should reproduce for checking printable over the byte[] array using new Byte(bytarray[incr]).intValue()+"\n"